# How to add JQuery phone masking to a label of grid view?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, masking

have a grid view which has label and i want to add phone masking to the label.It is working fine for a textbox outside grid view but not for a label inside grid view.

My code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       jQuery.noConflict();
       function init() {              
           jQuery("[id*=Label1]").mask("(999) 999-9999"); 

       };
       jQuery(function () { init(); });  
   </script>
```

Update:
My gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grabc" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"   CssClass="Grid" style="font-family:Calibri">
        <Columns>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Phone">
           <ItemTemplate>                                                          
             <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Phone") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
         </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Post your grid code when rendered in the browser..

Comment: you can check my updated code.@Bhavik

Comment: Use `$("[id$='Label1']")`

Comment: It still not helping.Does phone masking works for label???@Bharadwaj

Comment: I meant by the code on browser... After running your project view the source.. Post that code...

Comment: It works check it out here... http://jsfiddle.net/5H8gF/ The HTML code in the fiddle is the gridview when rendered to the browser...

Comment: Really thanks for the reply as you gave and idea that jquery phone masking works for label too. that's what i needed.Let me check with my code.@Bhavik